# ObjC/Cocoa NSRange: Range or index out of bounds

Tags: objective-c, nsrange

I'm trying to find an answer to a problem that's been puzzling me since last night.

```
NSRange searchRange.location = 0;
NSRange searchRange.length = [string length]; // > 2000 characters long
NSString *substring = @"substring"; // Occurs within string several times

NSRange substringRange = [string rangeOfString:substring options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:searchRange];

// Some code here. Create substring and add it to array.

// Move the search range on
searchRange.location = substringRange.location + substringRange.length;

// fails
substringRange = [string rangeOfString:substring options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:searchRange];
```

The first [string rangeOfString...] method gets called without a hitch, but the second call results in the following error:

> *** -[__NSCFString rangeOfString:options:range:locale:]: Range or index out of bounds

From what I can tell, the problem is caused by the assignment of the new value to searchRange.location -- removing that statement results in a successful second call to the method. Looking at the debugger, the values seem to be as predicted -- nothing outside of range -- and I'm left screaming at the monitor.

It's just simple addition... isn't it?

Comment: You probably don't want to declare `NSRange searchRange` twice.

Comment: I have no idea what are you trying to do.

Comment: @Radu performing arithmetic on a struct?

Comment: I think we need to know what are you actually trying to do dud.

Comment: The problem is it's at the end of the string and you're triyng perform  a rangeOfstring from a range that doesn't exist in your string so if you tell us what you want to do ,high level view, we might be abel to help

Comment: Okay. This should all happen within a for loop but as the second method doesn't even get called, I've removed it to simplify the example. The thinking is: search string for substring (which is known, for debugging purposes, to occur several times). Take that substring and add it to an array. Move the searchRange.location to the end of the substring location. (logging to the console, values seem ok: "new searchRange.location: 208 searchRange.length: 2060") Find the next occurrence.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you modify the location but you don't modify the length. The result is a range that is too long. The solution is to reduce the length by the same amount as you increase the location.

Comment: I guess you're '1' out after the calculation?

Comment: This works: searchRange.length = [string length] - searchRange.location;